# How can I programmatically open an OnPoint map to specific coordinates?

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude, coordinates

We have an [OnPoint](http://www.oriongis.com/content.asp?MainCataID=5) server at work and I'm wondering how to open the mapping service and having it zoom in to my specified latitude and longitude.

The reason I ask is because we have an application at work that requires our users to manually type in the latitude and longitude into our system for searching. Our application does have this information so we'd like to offer the users a link.

[Here](http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=Dairy%20Queen,%20103%20Bradford%20Street,%20Barrie,%20ON%20L4N%203A9&hl=en&ll=44.386369,-79.687443&spn=0.015288,0.033023&sll=49.890392,-97.15292&t=h&z=16&iwloc=suck) is an example URL that you could plug into Google Maps.

[Here](http://maps.barrie.ca/Resident/WebPages/Map/FundyViewer.aspx) is an example of a GIS system running OnPoint.

I do see if their promotional PDF clearly states that you can perform searches via URL queries but I see *zero* documentation.

```
 Launch OnPoint from external applications by sending URL to OnPoint Website
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create URLs for use by OnPoint, you can use AdvancedGenerateURL tool in the OnPoint Administration console.  This tool will generate a URL that OnPoint can use, based on what parameters you want to use to set the map extent.  You can then copy and paste the URL to tweak it for you needs.

Here is an example of the structure of an OnPoint URL.
[image]

To pass coordinates to OnPoint, your need to specify the max/min XY coordinates for OnPoint to set the extents.  Here is an example of a URL to set extents using coordinates.

[image]
This information is available in the OnPoint Application Design Guide.  There should be a copy of this pdf that came with the application install.

You can also pass just the lat/long if your know the coordinate system id.  In the screenshot below the highlighted values are the lat/long, and the number following them is the coordinate system id.  This url will pass the lat/long and add a labeled point to the map.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Turns out our OnPoint administrators disabled this functionality. I'm in the process of getting it enabled. In the meantime (since it might take a while before I get the documentation), how do you determine the max y/x and min x/y given only the latitude and longitude?

Comment: I'm still waiting for work to provide me with the documentation. In the mean time could you tell me how to convert latitude and longitude to min a/y and max x/y?

Comment: I did manage to find `GenerateUrl/GenerateUrlPage.aspx/GetURL` which I can call via code while passing `{\"labelX\":\"{0}\",\"labelY\":\"{1}\",\"label\":\"HERE PEOPLE!\",\"selectedImageId\":\"\",\"userName\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}`. However, that doesn't seem to be giving me the proper min/max x/y. I must be missing something.

Comment: After digging around in the documentation, there is a url that will pass just the lat/long and add a labeled point to the map.  You need to pass the coord system id in the url.  I'll edit my initial answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Much appreciated. I tried plugging in my coordinates as well as modify the coordinate system id, however that simply puts my label outside of our mapping area. Must be plugging in some wrong parameters. Anyway, at least the documentation confirms that what I want to do is possible. :)